# Should we include methods in prototypes for ES6 Classes for performance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6, prototype

So as I learn more about the `Prototypal Inheritance` in JS, I read the following in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS#Creating_our_finished_constructor) article (read lines just above this link)

> Note that when we are calling our constructor function, we are defining greeting() every time, which isn't ideal. To avoid this, we can define functions on the prototype instead, which we will look at later.

The idea recommended is to add `properties` on Function and `methods` on the `prototype` (read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes#Modifying_prototypes))

```
Person.prototype.farewell = function() {
  alert(this.name.first + ' has left the building. Bye for now!');
};
```

I read at multiple places that this way

- The object creation is faster, since the `farewell` is not created for every object creation. This is because it is created once and attached to the `prototype`, and all the objects **link** to the `prototype`.
- The methods are looked up on the `prototypal chain` so every object links to the same method on the `prototype`.

Now comes the ES6 class. I have the following code

```
class Person {
    constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
        this.name = {
            first: first,
            last: last
        };
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = interests;
    }

    greeting () {
        console.log("Hi! I am", this.name.first);
    }

    farewell () {
        console.log(this.name.first, "has left the building. Bye for now!");
    }
}
```

It seems that with this approach `greeting` and `farewell` will be created again (following up on same logic as Functions since `class` is a syntactic sugar)

So, I changed the class to

```
class Person {
    constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
        this.name = {
            first: first,
            last: last
        };
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = interests;
    }
}

Person.prototype.greeting = function () {
    console.log("Hi! I am", this.name.first);
}

Person.prototype.farewell = function () {
    console.log(this.name.first, "has left the building. Bye for now!");
}
```

**Question**
1. Does the latter way (Adding methods on `prototype` in `ES6 class`) is a recommended way?
2. Does the logic of `class` and traditional `new Function` to create a new object align? `Copy` vs `Method on Prototype`?

Please let me know if there is anything else I am missing

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

After few answers, I retried my examples and confirmed the answers. My code looks like

```
class Phone {
  constructor(company, name, color, price) {
    this.company = company;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;
    this.price = price;
  }

  print() {
    console.log(this.company, this.name, this.color, this.price);
  }
}

class Apple extends Phone {
    constructor(name, color, price) {
        super("Apple", name, color, price);
        this.companyWork = "ClosedSource";
    }
}

let iPhone11 = new Apple("iPhone11", "black", 900);
iPhone11.print()
```

After I ran this code, I can confirm that `print()` is available on `Phone.prototype`
[image]

Comment: Those two code snippets do the same thing. Class methods are properties of the class's prototype object.

Comment: thank you @Paulpro, can you cite a reference please?

Comment: "*It seems that with this approach greeting and farewell will be created again*" - uh, no. They're not placed inside the `constructor`, they're located inside the `class` syntax, which puts them on the classes' prototype object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already discovered, `class` definitions put methods on the prototype.  You asked for a reference so here's a little code you can run to see for yourself:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
        this.name = {
            first: first,
            last: last
        };
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.interests = interests;
    }

    greeting () {
        console.log("Hi! I am", this.name.first);
    }

    farewell () {
        console.log(this.name.first, "has left the building. Bye for now!");
    }
}

let p = new Person("Jack", "Beanstalk", 201, "giant", ["crushing things", "stomping things"]);

console.log("Person", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person));

console.log("p", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(p));

let p_prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(p);

console.log("p_prototype === Person.prototype is ", p_prototype === Person.prototype);

console.log("Person.prototype", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Person.prototype));
```

That generates this output:

```
Person [ 'length', 'prototype', 'name' ]
p [ 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'interests' ]
p_prototype === Person.prototype is true
Person.prototype [ 'constructor', 'greeting', 'farewell' ]
```

So, you can draw these conclusions:

1. The `Person` class has only the expected properties for a constructor function and the prototype object, none of the class-defined methods are there.
2. An instance of the class has only the expected data properties that are assigned in the constructor, none of the class-defined methods are on the object itself.
3. The prototype you get from an instance is the same as the prototype of the class (thus no new object is created for each instance).
4. The `Person.prototype` has the expected methods from the `class` definition on it plus a property that points to the constructor itself (used in inheriting and calling derived constructor).

So, you can verify from this that methods defined with the `class` syntax go on the `Classname.prototype` object and that object is shared with all instances.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK

1. No, it's not a recommended way.  Class methods are created as methods on prototype.  In other words classes are just syntactic sugar for regular prototypal inheritance.
2. In both cases methods won't be created multiple times if multiple objects are created.  Methods will be created only once.

Comment: Thanks @krl, could you please cite a reference on "Class methods are created as methods on prototype". Thank you. I tried looking up but could not find an official answer

Comment: @daydreamer Will this do? _...the class keyword is introduced in ES2015, but is syntactical sugar, JavaScript remains prototype-based_

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain